# Replicate a nested for-loop with a dict-comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary

Given the following code:

#### minimal example of list of lists:

```py
c = [['dog', 'Sg', 'Good'], ['cat', 'Pl', 'Okay'], ['dog', 'Pl', 'Bad'],
     ['dog', 'Sg', 'Good'], ['cat', 'Pl', 'Okay'], ['dog', 'Pl', 'Okay'],
     ['dog', 'Sg', 'Good'], ['cat', 'Sg', 'Good'], ['dog', 'Pl', 'Bad'],
     ['dog', 'Sg', 'Good'], ['cat', 'Pl', 'Okay'], ['dog', 'Pl', 'Bad']]
```

#### create `sets` of words from `c`

```py
outer_keys = set()
inner_keys = set()
for x in c:
    outer_keys.add(x[0])
    inner_keys |= set(x[1:])
```

#### create `dict` with `for loop`

```py
Lemma = dict()
for i in outer_keys:
    j_d = dict()
    for j in inner_keys:
        j_d[j] = 0
    j_d[i] = 0  # this is the line I can't replicate with a comprehension
    Lemma[i] = j_d
```

#### `for loop` result:

```py
{'dog': {'Okay': 0, 'Pl': 0, 'Good': 0, 'Bad': 0, 'Sg': 0, 'dog': 0},
 'cat': {'Okay': 0, 'Pl': 0, 'Good': 0, 'Bad': 0, 'Sg': 0, 'cat': 0}}
```

#### using [`dict comprehension`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

- This is where I need assistance.  I haven't been able to replicate the `for-loop` with the `dict` comprehension

```py
Lemma = {j: {i: 0 for i in inner_keys} for j in outer_keys}
```

Note: `dog` should be inside the `value` of outer `dog` and the same for `cat`

#### My `dict comprehension` result:

```py
{'dog': {'Okay': 0, 'Pl': 0, 'Good': 0, 'Bad': 0, 'Sg': 0},
 'cat': {'Okay': 0, 'Pl': 0, 'Good': 0, 'Bad': 0, 'Sg': 0}}
```

#### Question:

- How can I replicate the result of the `for-loop` with the `dict comprehension`?
- Order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dict.fromkeys` together with `inner_keys | {j}`:

```
>>> {j: dict.fromkeys(inner_keys | {j}, 0) for j in outer_keys}
{'cat': {'Bad': 0, 'Good': 0, 'Okay': 0, 'Pl': 0, 'Sg': 0, 'cat': 0},
 'dog': {'Bad': 0, 'Good': 0, 'Okay': 0, 'Pl': 0, 'Sg': 0, 'dog': 0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new `dict` from your inner dict

```
>>> {j: dict({i: 0 for i in inner_keys}, **{j:0}) for j in outer_keys}
{'dog': {'Bad': 0, 'Good': 0, 'Okay': 0, 'Sg': 0, 'dog': 0, 'Pl': 0}, 'cat': {'Bad': 0, 'Good': 0, 'Okay': 0, 'Sg': 0, 'Pl': 0, 'cat': 0}}
```